# Motivation for Gamma, exponential, & chi-squared distributions

Tags: distributions, gamma-distribution, intuition, exponential-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

I understand the binomial, geometric, Poisson, and normal distributions. However, I don't understand the usefulness or difference between the following: Gamma, exponential, and chi-squared. So far, it seems that certain populations just inherently have different properties and thus different distributions are used to deal with them. Given a new population how and why would one decide to use the Gamma, exponential, or chi-squared distributions? (I'm a beginner in statistics and am trying to wrap my head around the application of distributions)